# What is a better name for a randomesque process that never picks the last picked?

Tags: random-variables, terminology

I'm trying to find the name (if such exists) for a certain process:-

Assume a fixed set $S$.  An infinite stationary process ($P$) acts on $S$ to select members. $P$ does not remove them from the set, just selects. $P$ selects the members (truly) randomly, BUT is tweaked to never select the previous one. So if the current selected $(x_n)$ was $v$, $P$ will next $(x_{n+1})$ pick  one of the other members, not $v$. The memory effect/lag only concerns the last chosen so $x_{n+2}$ can be $v$ again.  And so on.

Clearly $P$ is not "random" per se as $v$ could be picked consecutively in that case. Is there some simple term for describing $P$, or do I have to keep writing out the above paragraph?

Comment: +1 for the word 'randomesque'.

Comment: I would not think that this has a name, at least not one in widespread use.  Of course, at each stage it's just a uniform draw, though the sample space changes from turn to turn.  In any case, I'd write it out.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I've heard the term "random walk" for a stochastic process that doesn't have the same output twice in a row. It's nowhere near what you're looking for (its the sum of a stream of random{-1, 1}), but maybe it's a place to start?

Comment: This just sounds like a Markov Chain to me. The current state is the last picked value, and the next state is random, but with zero probability of being the same state again. It ***is*** still "random". Nothing in the definition of random requires that every value has positive probability.

Comment: Agree with @Joe . Explicitly the Markov matrix is$ \frac{1}{s-1}(\mathbf{1}-I)$ where ${\bf 1}=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
1 & 1\\
\cdots &  & \cdots\\
1 &  &  & 1
\end{array}\right]$ is the "all ones" matrix, and $s$ is the number of objects in $S$.

Comment: @rhkoulen, in fact, a "random walk" is exactly what the OP is looking for, if you consider the random walk to be on a fully connected graph with vertices $S$.

Comment: @Joe I've come from the crypto forum, and we concern ourselves with 'uniformly' random. And that leads to $n$ repeats with probability $  \frac{1}{{|S|}^n}  $. That's where my confusion came from as I don't have uniformity in this case. Thanks.

Comment: It's common for people to use the word random when they actually mean uniformly at random, but I wanted to make sure that you knew that is still just a random process. The fact that the "memory" only goes back to the last pick is called the Markov property, assuming that pick is the "state" of the system.